# Report, how to start with a "right"-page?

Tags: report, double-sided

I am writing a report and use the following preamble:

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm,bmargin=30mm]{geometry}
```

Now latex think that the first page is a "left" page, any way I can set the first page to be a "right" page?

Comment: The first page, the one with number 1, is for sure a right page. Perhaps explain why you think differently.

Comment: I agree, LaTeX definitely "thinks" that page 1 is a right page, using your preamble. Perhaps your PDF or DVI viewer thinks differently? Otherwise, what do you mean?

Comment: Perhaps if your inner margin were not the same as the outer, you could see a difference?

Comment: Adobe Reader by default displays things incorrectly. There is a 'show title page' option (or something like that) somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by the "first page", but try it without the `twoside` option:

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm,bmargin=30mm]{geometry}
```

Comment: @latexmp BTW, you need to work on accepting a few more answers to your questions (:-) !!